# PHP - retrieving application settings once from INI, but where should I store it for global use?

Tags: php, session, variables, global

I am writing a very large application that requires an initial query of a DB or INI file to retrieve application settings.  I then want to store it once globally so that I don't have to keep querying a DB or reading an INI file for every page load.

I have a pseudo bootstrap file that I include in every PHP file.  Inside this bootstrap file, I initiate application paths, setup the session etc.  I also want this file to perform the intial DB or INI read and store the application settings globally.  I was thinking of using $_SESSION but I'm not so sure if this is a good idea or not.

The type of data that I want to store once globally: directory integration credentials (AD, Kerberos, etc), whether or not the server instance is behind a proxy, DB connection credentials, and whether or not logging is enabled or not.  Additionally, I want the user to have deep control on what logs to keep: i.e. "when users log in", "when there is an error", "when a new calendar event is created", etc.  These various logging actions occur throughout my application and I don't want to query the DB or read an INI each time to check whether a particular logging setting has been enabled.

Here is what I was thinking re: SESSION vars:

```
if( !isset($_SESSION["settings_retrieved"] ){
// begin DB or INI read here
$_SESSION["use_proxy"] = 1;
$_SESSION["ad_user"] = "authorized_user001";
$_SESSION["log_login"] = 1;
$_SESSION["log_error"] = 1;
// etc...
}
```

What do you think?  Should I store these global application variables in SESSION?

Comment: Yes; that's what it's there for.

Comment: Are there any security concerns I should be aware of?  I was thinking SESSION was more for user-specific settings, where what I need is to store application settings that don't really depend on any specific type of user.

Comment: @jnpcl you are wrong, sessions aren't for global settings. and there is no gain anyway

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I was under the impression that these settings may be different per instance of the application. (Initially, settings are read from the INI, but any user-specific changes would be stored in the SESSION var)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ini file is already a storage you're looking for.
So, keep it - you don't need anything else.

Sessions is not something ethereal. It's the same file or database record. So, you're going to make that filesystem or database lookup anyway, making your system overcomplicated with no real gain.

Comment: Would that mean I would have to parse the INI file from disk every single time a new PHP file is loaded?  Isn't that inefficient?  Is there some sort of application / server-level cache I can use?

Comment: @Freddie why do you think that to parse the SESSION file from disk every single time a new PHP file is loaded would be any better? Why it is your concern at all? Do you have any single problem with parsing ini files? Why don't you worry that PHP has to parse your PHP code every time PHP file is loaded?

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I was missing the fact that SESSION is actually read from disk.  Now that I know that, I get your point that SESSION and INI are practically the same thing because they are both from the disk.  I was thinking SESSION was stored in pre-allocated memory somewhere for some reason and thus would be faster.  Thanks for clarifying and answering my question.